# Python: Changing indivividual elements in a list of bool

Tags: list, python-3.x, boolean

I have a list of bool as below:

```
[False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

I wish to change the last 2 elements (or any indices of my choice) to True:

```
[False, False, False, False, True, True]
```

Comment: Do you always want to change the last n elements or any arbitrary index? For arbitrary index you can just do ```list[index] = True```. For the n last elements you can do ```list = list[:-n] + [True] * n```.

Comment: The last 2 was an example. I would like to change any section like `list[2:3]=True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, given arbitrary indices `i` and `j` (where `i <= j`) where you want to set `list[i:j]` = `True` you can do the following:

`list = list[:i] + [True] * (j-i) + list[j:]`